# is their are any alternative methods instead of iterator for my requirement

Tags: java, list, collections, hashmap, iterator

I am having a map `HashMap<sId, List<Bannas>>` where `sId` are similar for many Id of the list and I am also having one method getListbySId (in sId).
by using this method I can get a list of values with similar values on based sId.
now I have to remove a value from a list of values based on sId then it is possible by iteration process where I can compare id of the list of values. if it is matched I will remove it. instead of this method, anyone can say an alternative method to remove the values or get the values without changing the requirement. I cant provide a code plz help me.

Comment: I guess `map.keySet().removeIf( id -> id.equals( otherSId ) );` is what You need…

Comment: can u explain more in remove if condition

Comment: @Kaplan `map.keySet().removeIf( id -> id.equals( otherSId ) );` does exactly the same as `map.remove( otherSId );`, just less efficient due to the linear iteration.

Comment: thanks  for ur answer

Comment: @Holger OP spoke of several similar sID's that have to be deleted. So the construct seemed more appropriate to me, than the `remove` solution that deletes only one ID. `…removeIf( id -> id.equals( sID1 ) || id.equals( sID2 ) || id.equals( sID3 ) );`

Comment: @Kaplan depending on the map’s size, even three remove actions will be more efficient than running a `removeIf` over the entire map. For more keys, you can even use `map.keySet().removeAll(Set.of(sID1,sID2, sID3…));` which will choose whichever strategy is better for the map’s current size and the argument set’s size automatically. Besides that, it’s not clear what “similar” means in a sentence like “where sId are similar for many Id of the list” from the OP.

Comment: @Holger The OP's question is titled "…alternative methods instead of iterator…". So You had to surround Your `remove()` at least with some kind of a loop, so that the OP can find the desired sID's. I don't think the OP has a key-list to delete specific `Bannas`.

Comment: @Kaplan Huh? `keySet().removeAll(Set.of(…))` *is* an alternative to an iterator. I don’t know what the OP’s “similar” actually means. The OP’s sentence “where sId are similar for many Id of the list” rather suggests that it actually means “equal”, as all elements of one *list* are mapped to the same key of the map. As long as we don’t know what the OP really wants, there is no point in providing examples of unnecessary uses of `removeIf`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove some values from `List<Bannas>` matching some `id` field of `Bannas` object (it may be `sId` or another id), it is possible to use `Collection::removeIf` method:

```java
 //

public static void removeValuesById(HashMap<String, List<Bannas>> map, String sId, String anotherId) {
    map.getOrDefault(sId, Collections.emptyList())
       .removeIf(banna -> banna.getId().equals(anotherId));
}
```

**Update**
Another solution *not relying on implementation of `Collections.emptyList`* should handle a case when a key `sId` is not in the map:

```java
public static void removeValuesById(HashMap<String, List<Bannas>> map, String sId, String anotherId) {
    Optional.ofNullable(map.get(sId))
            .ifPresent(list -> 
                list.removeIf(banna -> banna.getId().equals(anotherId))
    );      
}
```

Comment: A lot of the immutable collections are designed to throw unconditionally when mutation methods are invoked, regardless of whether they would cause a modification or not. `Collections.emptyList().removeIf(…);` may be the exception to the rule but I would avoid creating code relying on it.

Comment: @Holger, no exception is thrown for the list returned by `Collections.emptyList`, `removeIf` is overridden in `Collections::EmptyList` [to return false, line 4525](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Collections.java#l4525)

Comment: I know, but is this guaranteed by any specification? [The general contract](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate)) regarding `UnsupportedOperationException` is “*Implementations may throw this exception if a matching element cannot be removed or if, in general, removal is not supported.*”

Comment: `UnsupportedOperationException` would have been thrown if the empty list had been wrapped into `Collections.unmodifiableList` or `List.of`.  For empty list there's no element to traverse, so `removeIf` should not throw this exception.

Comment: For `List.of()` or `Collections.unmodifiableList(Collections.emptyList())`, there’s also no element to traverse, still, those collections throw unconditionally, as the specification allows. So, where do you see the *guaranty* that `Collections.emptyList().removeIf(…)` will never throw like `List.of().removeIf(…)` does?

Comment: `Collections.emptyList` does not seem to be implemented as _strictly_ immutable -- such operations as `clear`, `sort`, `replaceAll`,`remove(Object o)` do not throw this exception either. Also, the statement _Implementations may throw this exception..._ does NOT mean that this exception will _always_ be thrown even if the operation is impossible.

Comment: I know, it *does not seem to be* strictly immutable. OpenJDK has implemented it that way. Your code works with the current version of the reference implementation. I never said otherwise. The question is whether it is a good idea to create code *relying* on this unspecified behavior. As said in my first comment, I would avoid it.

Comment: @Holger i had utilized List.of().removeIf() method it was usefull to me. thanks for ur reply on answers

Comment: @AkhilNallapaneni, `removeIf` **cannot** be used with `List.of()` because `List.of` returns strictly immutable list and `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown.